# How to use concurrency to make this code run faster

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency

I am generating data to write to a file in a loop.

```
while True:
    data = generate_data()
    write_to_file(data)
```

Since writing to the file can be slow I want to start generating the next set of data while writing the current set. How can I generate data and write to the file concurrently?

Comment: What kind of system are you running on where file writing is slow?

Comment: What does `write_to_file()` actually do?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is depends on time cost of saving data and calculating data, if we pretend that both of them need almost same time we just need a main process and a sub process.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe
import os

def generator(conn):
    print("process id:",os.getpid())
    while True:
        data = generate_data()
        conn.send(data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parent_conn, child_conn = Pipe()
    p = Process(target=generate_data, args=(child_conn,))
    p.start()
    print("process id:", os.getpid())
    while True:
        write_to_file(parent_conn.recv())   
    p.join()
```

Also suggest you to save data on ram and then move it to hard drive when you want.

Comment: There is no advantage here in terms of performance. You have a single process and a communication mechanism (the pipe). It's effectively synchronous. You also have two infinite loops

Comment: @DarkKnight We have a main process and one sub process so we will have two process you can add two print(os.getpid()) to function and main process to understand it.

Comment: @DarkKnight at first sub process calculate data while main process waiting for result. Then main process start writing data while sub process calculating next data. I have used pipe to keep order of data.

Comment: not bad, but the overhead of using a subprocess there might overtake all gains. This same code could use multi-threading and queues.